# Problems with Journal Submissions due to arXiv Submission?

Tags: arxiv, lo.logic, soft-question, advice, journals

Hello, 
I wanted to ask people if they know of any journals that will not accept papers for submission if they have been already posted on arxiv. I am personally interested in Logic Journals, but people can contribute their experiences from any field. 
I guess I could read all the fine print the publishers have on their webpages, but I am trying to see if anyone had any problems.

Just to contribute my part, I didn't have problems with the Journal of Symbolic Logic and the Annals of Pure and Applied Logic.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Publishing.mathforge.org is more interested in changes to the system, but is a better place than MathOverflow for this question.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.03.14

Comment: Reading "all the fine print" does not help much, since this fine print often self-contradictory, (deliberately) confusing and far away from the reality (often, editors don't even know the rules of their publisher).

Comment: Although I have no experience with logic journals, I have plenty
with other math journals. I can't imagine any journal worth anything
to adopt such an outrageous policy. Submission to the arxiv would
be the equivalent of putting it on your web page or mailing preprints
the old fashioned way. It is not the equivalent to being published.

Comment: While I’d expect no journal to make problems (as Donu says), I can confirm that the Journal of Logic and Computation and Mathematical Logic Quarterly are OK (in the sense that it seems to be in line with their Copyright Transfer Agreement, and they didn’t make any problems to me in practice).

Comment: There are two questions here: (1) Will the journal accept papers which are already on arXiv, and (2) Do the submission policies of the journal *explicitly allow* submission of articles on arXiv.  (There is also (3) Does the journal *explicitly allow or disallow* posting of the revised, refereed version of your article to arXiv.)  As darij points out, these are different questions, with different answers.  For any reputable journal, the answer to (1) is probably "yes"; the answers for (2) and (3) will depend on the journal, and may be hazy.  It'd be nice to see answers to these here.

Comment: Ok, the post was made to a community-wiki.
The reason I am asking this question is that arXiv publishes most articles under the Creative Commons license which may allow a couple of things that publishers wouldn't like. For instance, multiple commercial publications of the same paper maybe allowed under the Creative Commons license, but most publishers ask the author to give them the exclusive right for publication. So my question is whether in practice these "legal details" actually come in. 

Comment: why was this question closed? and who cares whether it's community-wiki or not? It's definitely an issue of interest to the mathematical community, I don't see why it shouldn't belong to MO.

Comment: I voted to close it because it is asking for examples of something that simply doesn't happen.  If this were an actual problem besetting mathematicians, then I would support keeping the question open; however, as it stands I suspect that it would just generate a lot of junk answers (journal publishing being a "hot" topic).  If the OP or someone else can give one single example of a math journal not accepting submissions of papers that are on the arXiv, then I would vote to reopen.

Comment: @Putman: If this is really not happening, that's pretty good news to me. My impression is that the legal language does create some problems, but I maybe wrong. I just wanted to see if this is happening in practice or not. The post is not about journal publishing in general. It is very specific.

Comment: @andy putman: I think that (especially) for graduate students (like myself), it's a useful question. While your comment on the non-existence of such journals is comforting, all the rest of the information generated with such a simple question gives me certainty.

Comment: I did not vote to close, but I think discussion could more profitably be sent to http://publishing.mathforge.org The only perceived downside I can think of is that pseudonymity is discouraged there, but on a topic like this I think that is actually a plus. Moreover, the more people who get usefully involved in, or are aware of, said forum, the better, IMO.

Comment: @Andy: I never heard of this happening, but I do know of some people who are concerned about this and would not put their papers on the Arxiv for "copyright reasons". I think the answers given so far are already useful, and see no reason to close this question just because it might generate junk answers. If it does, we can close it then. Voting to reopen.

Comment: In light of the discussion here, I started a meta thread.  Please vote this comment up so that it appears above the fold.  http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1325/journals-not-allowing-papers-that-are-arxived/

Comment: Never happens?  Maybe, but who knows?  Some years ago when Ohio State put in the requirement that Ph.D. theses should be put on-line in a certain way, there were some objections; so the policy was amended to allow the student to request a two-year embargo before it actually went on-line.  The stated reason is that certain top journals (perhaps medical-type journals?) absolutely would not publish research that is already available elsewhere.


Comment: @Gerald : Mathematics publishing and medical publishing are very different animals.  If there were an example of this, then I think it would be very widely known given how much people talk about open access these days and what not.  As I said, I could be very easily convinced that this is a real issue and would then vote to reopen.  Just one actual math journal with such a policy would be all that it would take!

Comment: @Ioannis: what do you mean 'arXiv publishes most papers under Creative Commons'. I never checked what most people do, but when you submit *you* get to choose the license. *And* the recommended thing to do is in fact to choose some 'arxiv license', not sure what the precise name is, except if you know what you are doing when choosing another license.  Alos I voted to reclose.

Comment: Yes, the arXiv allows the possibility of CC licenses, but I'm very confident that this is not the most common choice.

Comment: Since I still don't see why information couldn't be more profitably posted on http://publishing.mathforge.net , which also allows for proper discussion threads, I am voting to close. (Higher visibility of MO not sufficient reason to keep the question here, IMO.)

Comment: @Yemon - http://publishing.mathforge.org/

Comment: I see the question was reopened and then reclosed. I posted the same question on publishing.mathforge.org as people suggested. The consensus seems to be that the default arxiv license does not create any problems, but other licenses, e.g. creative commons (the two used by arxiv) and public domain, may create a problem. If you have any experience for the opposite, please share on publishing.mathforge.org/discussion/75/problems-with-journal-submissions-due-to-arxiv-submission/
Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

This recent article in the AMS notices has a handy checklist of the explicit rights given to authors in the standard publishing agreements with various publishers:

http://www.ams.org/notices/201203/rtx120300436p.pdf

Notice that there is often a distinction between the treatment of an  "author-created version" and the "publisher version" of an article.

Answer (score 1):

William Stein has a site on "Journal Copyright Gossip"...
[LINK](http://modular.math.washington.edu/copyright/)

Comment: This was a great site, but it hasn't been updated in about ten years, and many journal policies may have changed in the meantime.

Comment: They have definitely changed in the meantime...